# How to find an equation for the surface that the distance from its point to x-axis is three times the distance from its point to yz-plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

As title says, how does one find an equation for the surface consisting of all points $P$ for which the distance from $P$ to the x-axis is three times the distance from $P$ to the $yz$-plane?

Comment: What have you tried? For instance, suppose the $y$ and $z$ coordinates are given; what are the possible values for the $x$ coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that the distance from $(x,y,z)$ to the $yz$-plane is $|x|$, and the distance from $(x,y,z)$ to the $x$-axis is $\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

what is its locus if ratio $ x/y $ is constant and you rotate it on x-axis?